# Cannot connect QnA maker into Bot Frameowrk Emulator

Tags: azure, chatbot, azure-qna-maker

I am trying to load my QnA maker in addition to my QnA chat bot from Azure into Bot Framework Emulator.

I have been able to load my chat bot in successfully  with it returning a response. I have entered the knowledge base data it required inside the Azure chat bot settings as well and the Visual Studio code (C#). But when I enter text into the chat bot inside of the bot framework emulator it replies with: `Please set QnAKnowledgebaseId, QnAAuthKey and QnAEndpointHostName (if applicable) in App Settings. Learn how to get them at https://aka.ms/qnaabssetup.`

[Screen shot of what is displayed when I make contact with my chatbot inside of the bot framework emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGyj3.jpg)

Any help with resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QnA Maker is generally available from May 2018. New architecture is built on Azure, where the runtime is now deployed on Azure App.

Now, if you are using new QnA Maker GA, it requires three parameters to get connect with Azure Bot Web App Bot. KnowledgebaseID, AuthKey & Host Name.

Host name is nothing but Web App URL deployed whiled creating QnA Maker service,
*appname.azurewebsites.net/qnamaker*

You have to provide this in Application Settings in Azure portal or alternatively in Constructor code part.

Thanks!